# Не отображается DIV блок

Tags: css, html

Всем привет! Не могу понять почему `div` блок `functionts` не отображается.

```css
body {
  background: #EDEEF0;
}

.upper {
  border: 2px solid #4A76A8;
  width: 1923px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #4A76A8;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.photka {
  width: 230px;
  height: 270px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 628px;
  border: 1px solid #E3E4E8;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

img1 {
  margin-left: 462px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

avatar {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
}

functionts {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 4px solid red;
  background: red;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class='upper'>
  <img1>
    <img src='vk.png'></img1>
</div>

<div class='photka'>
  <avatar>
    <img width=2 00 height=2 20 src='https://pp.userapi.com/c851024/v851024902/a860e/Q2VN9Ztdji0.jpg'>
  </avatar>
  </img>
</div>
<div class='functionts'>Редактировать</div>
```

Comment: перед классами в CSS нужно ставить `.`

Comment: А что за магические теги у вас? `<img1>` и `</img>` и `<avatar>`? почему не использовать обычные теги с нужным классом?

Comment: @L.F.C. html то такое позволяет, но только мне непонятно зачем, тем более что примера использования не приведено =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков я только начал изучать css и html. Можете привести пример как было бы правильно употребить?

Comment: https://webref.ru/css/selector/class и https://webref.ru/css/selector/id и https://webref.ru/html/img

Comment: @ГенаПевко Употребить что? тег `<img>` не требует закрытия(для него не нужно писать `</img>`), тегов `<img1>` и `<avatar>` вообще не существует, хотите контейнер - делайте `<div class='avatar'>` и соответственно `<div class='img1'>` как обратиться к тому или иному элементу - выше вам привели 2 ссылки.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков на такие вещи обычно обращают внимание? разве они не будут работать одинаково?

Comment: @ГенаПевко Нашел вам бесплатный курс [по HTML](https://webref.ru/course/html-basics) и [по CSS](https://webref.ru/course/css-basics), пройдите, поймете

Comment: @ГенаПевко если бы это были эквивалентные записи - я бы ни слова вам не написал что так делать не стоит без понимания что вы делаете. но нет, `<avatar>` и `<div class='avatar'>` **не эквивалентны, и могут вести себя по разному**

Comment: @L.F.C большое спасибо за помощь

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков большое спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Заменяй, так будет работать:

```css
body{
 background:#EDEEF0;
}

.upper{
 border: 2px solid #4A76A8;
 width:1923px;
 height:40px;
 background:#4A76A8;
 margin-left:-15px;
 margin-top: -10px;
}

.photka{
 width:230px;
 height:270px;
 margin-top:15px;
 margin-left:628px;
 border: 1px solid #E3E4E8;
 background:#FFFFFF;
 border-radius: 4px;
}

.img1{
 margin-left:462px;
 margin-top:1px;
}

.avatar{
 height:200px;
 width:200px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 margin-left:15px;
 margin-top:10px;
 float:left;
}

.functionts{
 width:200px;
 height:30px;
 border:4px solid red;
 background:red;
 clear:both;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>vk</title>
  </head> 
  <body>
    <div class = 'upper'>
      <div class = 'img1'>
        <img src = 'vk.png'>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class = 'photka'>
      <div class = 'avatar'>
        <img width = 200 height = 220 src = 'https://pp.userapi.com/c851024/v851024902/a860e/Q2VN9Ztdji0.jpg'>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class = 'functionts'>
      Редактировать
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

В комментариях в верстке описаны замечания и ответ на вопрос

```css
body {
  background: #EDEEF0;
}

.upper {
  border: 2px solid #4A76A8;
  width: 1923px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #4A76A8;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.photka {
  width: 230px;
  height: 270px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 628px;
  border: 1px solid #E3E4E8;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

img1 {
  margin-left: 462px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

avatar {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
}


/* А тут пропустил точку перед селектором */

.functionts {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 4px solid red;
  background: red;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class='upper'>
  <!-- во избежания проблем в дальнейшем советую при использовании катомных
  элементов писать их черех тире например <img-1> </img-1>  -->
  <img1>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=img'>
  </img1>
</div>

<div class='photka'>
  <avatar>
    <!--<ava-tar></ava-tar>-->
    <!--сразу не заметил? это что за чудо значение (width=2 00) (height=2 20)
    пологаю что это 200 и 220 должны быть в кавычках-->
    <img width="200" height="220" src='https://pp.userapi.com/c851024/v851024902/a860e/Q2VN9Ztdji0.jpg'>
  </avatar>
  <!--</img> закрывающего тега </img> не существует, а если бы и существовал,
  то тут нарушена последовательность данный закрывающий тег должен быть на строку выше  -->
</div>
<div class='functionts'>Редактировать</div>
```